# ACE Editor Issue - Webpage Jumps on Editor Selection

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I am using the nifty ACE editor in Javascript on my webpage. However, I have come across an issue that I have been unable to find an answer for.

Sometimes when I select the text inside the editor (or just click in the editor at all), the webpage will quickly jump up a few hundred pixels. I have been unable to remove the issue, but I have found some conditions where it is more likely to occur:

- The web page is not full screen
- I have more than one ACE editor on the page
- The ACE editor is not entirely in view (part of it is scrolled above or below the widow)

Here are some screenshots just to give you an idea of what I mean.

1. [Before I click in the editor...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpK0H.png)
2. [After I click in the editor...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxIEC.png)
3. [Scrolling down so you can see the editor again...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfk3o.png)

This will happen nearly every time I click in the editor until I use the arrow keys to deselect.

I already checked to make sure I was using the most up-to-date version of ACE and have tried removing most of my extra Javascript that was manipulating it. The only thing I have not been able to pin-point any line of code from being the problem. It happens if I have only this Javscript working with the editors. I have systematically removed everything and it still does it.

```
var validatorEditor = ace.edit("custom-validator-editor");
validatorEditor.$blockScrolling = Infinity;
validatorEditor.setTheme("ace/theme/xcode");
validatorEditor.session.setMode({ path: "ace/mode/c_cpp", inline: true });
validatorEditor.resize();

var generatorEditor = ace.edit("output-generator-editor");
generatorEditor.$blockScrolling = Infinity;
// generatorEditor mode is set dynamically later on usually
generatorEditor.setTheme("ace/theme/xcode");
generatorEditor.resize();
```

Any ideas or suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After more digging into it for a few hours, I found that some CSS was causing the issue, namely

```
.parent-div{
    transform: translateX(10%);
}
```

Any value in there will make the editor jump when you focus on it.

Comment: It looks like the ace.js file modifies the transform value, so my changes to the CSS were overriding that change.